# how to set null the text when datepicker not clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

this is my code for datepicker

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var myDate = null;

        $("#tanggal").datepicker({

            altField: "#alternate",
            dateFormat:"yy:mm:dd",
            changeMonth:true,
            changeYear:true, 
            yearRange: '1970:2011',
            });
        });

    </script>
```

this is my code in html

```
<div><label>Start:</label><input id="alternate" type="text" name="dateStart" class="input_text" /></div>
    <div id="date"><div id="tanggal" ></div></div>
```

how to set the text is null when im not clicking the datepicker..thx

Comment: problem solved.. http://elementdesignllc.com/2009/09/jquery-ui-datepicker-inline-select/

Comment: It's exactly the behavior of the demo? http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: well what change do you want from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3CX2S/2/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean at startup to not have something pre-selected then use

```
$("#tanggal").datepicker( "setDate"  , myDate);
```

after you initialize the datepicker.

You can chain it and it becomes

```
 $("#tanggal").datepicker({

        altField: "#alternate",
        dateFormat:"yy:mm:dd",
        changeMonth:true,
        changeYear:true, 
        yearRange: '1970:2011',
    }).datepicker( "setDate"  , myDate);
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/XKBEq/